# Calling a function in children in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app with multiple `Views`. Each `View` has some number of mapped child `Entities`. Each of those entities has a state for whether or not it's collapsed/hidden called: `this.state.show`. Each `Entity` has a button that toggles the `show` state. *That all works fine.*

What I'd like to do is add a button up on the `View` that shows or hides all `Entities` at the same time. I thought this would be simple, but there are several complicating factors:

- I will eventually have multiple `Views` in the app each displaying the same data in different ways, so storing `show` in the lifted up prop isn't much of an option. I also don't want to store UI state in the file data, because that rubs me the wrong way.
- It makes it easier for me to understand what's happening when the state is stored directly on the `Entity` as a state rather than a prop of the `View`
- The React documentation (and everyone online) say that you shouldn't base state on props that change, and the number of `Entities` will change frequently. This is why I don't want to store the state of the children in the parent, because if I do and the entities change, then I have to somehow translate that change in props to a change in state, which is strongly cautioned against.
- If I were to use events, those events could spill over from one `View` to another.

What's the right strategy to pursue here? Am I not thinking "react" enough?

### View.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Entity from './Entity.jsx'
import Filter from './Filter.jsx'

class View extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="view main">
                {this.props.entities ? this.props.entities.map(
                    (e, i) => (
                        <Entity
                            entity={e}
                            propertyTypes={this.props.propertyTypes}
                            key={i}
                            index={i}
                            taglists={this.props.taglists}
                            ee={this.props.ee}
                        />
                    )
                ) : ""}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default View
```

### Entity.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Property from './Property.jsx'
import Event from './Event.jsx'
import Relationship from './Relationship.jsx'

class Entity extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            show: true
        }
        this.showHide = this.showHide.bind(this)
    }

    showHide() {
        this.setState({
            show: !this.state.show
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="entity" id={this.props.entity.name}>
                <div className="entity-header">
                    <h2>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            value={this.props.entity.name}
                            onChange={this.emit}
                            data-original={this.props.entity.name}
                            data-index={this.props.index}
                            data-event="rename"
                        ></input>
                    </h2>
                    <button
                        className="entity-collapse"
                        data-index={this.props.index}
                        onClick={this.showHide}
                    >{this.state.show ? "-" : "+"}</button>
                </div>
                <div className={this.state.show ? "entity-content" : "entity-content hidden"}>
                    ...
                    removed for clarity
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Entity
```

Comment: It looks like your nearly there, you have `collapseToggles:` in your `View`,  just use this, and remove the `show` state in your Entity.  Like mediaguru said, you can then update your Entity via it's props instead.  IOW: `show` becomes a prop instead of a state..

Comment: Sorry, I removed that section while I clean up the code. The reason that wasn't working was because when I updated the number of toggles based on the prop using `setState()` it triggered an infinite loop, so I was trying to find a different way of handling the situation.

Answer (score 2):

Your state should only be in the parent component, not any child components. You would then pass your functions and state as props to the children.

Comment: Good answer!!, for larger apps I would even say state shouldn't be even stored in the component.   Eg, maybe redux etc should be used, I don't use Redux personally as I find it way to cumbersome, but implemented my own using proxy's.

Comment: Agree Ketih. For any apps I've done to date I find Redux to be overkill, like throwing the whole toolbox at hammering a nail.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of storing state in a higher order component.

If you look at the code there is just one place where state is stored, and that's in the `View`,  This is known as single source of truth, and it makes coding in React much simpler.

For example if you click the `all` checkbox, all will check.  And if you individually check each one, the `all` and `none` will also keep in sync.

You can of course alter this to suite you needs, I've used checkbox here as it's easy to see the state changes working.

For larger applications the single source of truth method becomes even more important, and storing state inside React is best avoided.  This is what Redux is known for, like I mentioned in comments Redux is not something I use personally, but rolled my own single source of truth state management using proxy's, if I get time I might create an NPM module using this, as I'm sure other users would find it useful.

ps,. I've used React Hooks in the example as I believe it's the future of React, but it would be trivial to alter to use classes..

```js
const {useState, cloneElement} = React;


function MultiCheck(props) {
  const {checkallto, list, setList} = props;
  const checked = !list.some(f => f !== checkallto);
  return <div>
    <input
      onClick={() => {
        setList(new Array(list.length).fill(checkallto));
      }}
      onChange={() => {}}
      checked={checked} 
      type="checkbox"/>
    {props.children}
  </div>;
}


function View(props) {
  const [list, setList] = useState(new Array(props.children.length).fill(false));
 
  function setEntityChecked(ix) {
    return (check) => {
      const newlist = [...list];
      newlist[ix] = check;
      setList(newlist);
    };
  }
  
  const children = props.children.map((
    f, ix) => cloneElement(f, {key:ix, checked: list[ix],
      setChecked: setEntityChecked(ix)}));
  return <div>
    <MultiCheck checkallto={true} list={list} setList={setList}>
      All
    </MultiCheck>
    <MultiCheck checkallto={false} list={list} setList={setList}>
      None
    </MultiCheck>
    <hr/>
    {children}
  </div>;
}

function Entity(props) {
  const {checked, setChecked} = props;
  return <div><input
    checked={checked}
    onChange={()=>{}}
    onClick={() => setChecked(!checked)}
    type="checkbox"/>{props.children}</div>;
}


ReactDOM.render(<React.Fragment>
  <View>
    <Entity>One</Entity>
    <Entity>Two</Entity>
    <Entity>Two</Entity>
  </View>
</React.Fragment>, document.querySelector('#mount'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="mount"></div>
```